# What kind of architecture to build for an Android app with audio files?

Tags: php, android, audio, webserver

I want to create an Android app which basically deals with audio files.

The purpose of this app is to allow user to listen to audio files either by streaming or by downloading files. Audio files are categorized into channels and subchannels. Users can navigate to their desired category and get audio files related to that category and play them.

I have 10000 of audio files each sizing around 10 MB. I want to save the files to a centralized server (online hosting) and consume them in front-end using REST services.

Also, there needs to be a login form. Also, users can subscribe to channels if they are logged in.

As per my research, I know that I can do this by hiring a dedicated server and host files there. For the rest API I plan to use PHP.

Comment: where is your research code?

Comment: research code is from various links.